# Duplicated function in R outputting a non-duplicate entry

Tags: r

I have a data frame called "all_trip" which contains duplicate and non-duplicate entries. I use the `duplicate()` function on it, and it works except it outputs one entry that shouldn't be there.

```
> print_rows <- all_trip[1365:1370,]
> print_rows

# A tibble: 6 x 11
  ride_id          rideable_type started_at          ended_at            start_station_n~ end_station_name
  <chr>            <chr>         <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>            <chr>           
1 E1BC31FBB70B9296 classic_bike  2021-06-18 17:20:09 2021-06-18 17:27:13 Broadway & Wils~ Sheridan Rd & I~
2 69ACAA3687B7747E classic_bike  2021-06-18 17:20:09 2021-06-18 17:27:13 Broadway & Wils~ Sheridan Rd & I~
3 C24A66453F0C81DC docked_bike   2021-06-18 18:02:23 2021-06-18 18:15:14 Michigan Ave & ~ Michigan Ave & ~
4 D81BC7FFE8502818 electric_bike 2021-06-18 18:02:23 2021-06-18 18:15:14 Wolcott Ave & P~ Halsted St & Ar~
5 B67FA4D8DCC9BBFE classic_bike  2021-06-18 18:16:37 2021-06-18 18:40:39 Damen Ave & Pie~ Kedzie Ave & Pa~
6 4ECDC385B60B8D25 classic_bike  2021-06-18 18:16:37 2021-06-18 18:40:39 Lakefront Trail~ Glenwood Ave & ~
# ... with 5 more variables: start_lat <dbl>, start_lng <dbl>, end_lat <dbl>, end_lng <dbl>,
#   member_casual <chr>

> same_times_and_place <- all_trip[duplicated(all_trip[c("rideable_type", "start_station_name", "end_station_name", "start_lat", "start_lng", "end_lat", "end_lng", "member_casual")]), ]
> print_duplicate_rows <- same_times_and_place[291:293,]

# A tibble: 3 x 11
  ride_id          rideable_type started_at          ended_at            start_station_n~ end_station_name
  <chr>            <chr>         <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>            <chr>           
1 16921B172C161F30 docked_bike   2021-06-18 15:53:18 2021-06-18 18:03:09 LaSalle St & Il~ Sheffield Ave &~
2 C24A66453F0C81DC docked_bike   2021-06-18 18:02:23 2021-06-18 18:15:14 Michigan Ave & ~ Michigan Ave & ~
3 15DE43740FDDCCC1 classic_bike  2021-06-18 18:28:38 2021-06-18 18:37:07 Wells St & Ever~ Rush St & Cedar~
# ... with 5 more variables: start_lat <dbl>, start_lng <dbl>, end_lat <dbl>, end_lng <dbl>,
#   member_casual <chr>
```

Michigan and Wolcott are different, yet the duplicate() function thinks they are the same. What's stranger is that Michigan is output instead of Wolcott if the function thought they were the same thing.

I used `dput` on `all_trip[1367:1372,]`

```
trip_data <-
  structure(
    list(
      ride_id = c(
        "C24A66453F0C81DC",
        "D81BC7FFE8502818",
        "B67FA4D8DCC9BBFE",
        "4ECDC385B60B8D25",
        "A9ECC363F64D0767",
        "15DE43740FDDCCC1"
      ),
      rideable_type = c(
        "docked_bike",
        "electric_bike",
        "classic_bike",
        "classic_bike",
        "classic_bike",
        "classic_bike"
      ),
      started_at = structure(
        c(
          1624039343,
          1624039343,
          1624040197,
          1624040197,
          1624040918,
          1624040918
        ),
        tzone = "UTC",
        class = c("POSIXct",
                  "POSIXt")
      ),
      ended_at = structure(
        c(
          1624040114,
          1624040114,
          1624041639,
          1624041639,
          1624041427,
          1624041427
        ),
        tzone = "UTC",
        class = c("POSIXct",
                  "POSIXt")
      ),
      start_station_name = c(
        "Michigan Ave & Oak St",
        "Wolcott Ave & Polk St",
        "Damen Ave & Pierce Ave",
        "Lakefront Trail & Wilson Ave",
        "Wells St & Evergreen Ave",
        "Wells St & Evergreen Ave"
      ),
      end_station_name = c(
        "Michigan Ave & Oak St",
        "Halsted St & Archer Ave",
        "Kedzie Ave & Palmer Ct",
        "Glenwood Ave & Morse Ave",
        "Rush St & Cedar St",
        "Rush St & Cedar St"
      ),
      start_lat = c(
        41.90096,
        41.8712378333333,
        41.9093960065,
        41.965845,
        41.906724,
        41.906724
      ),
      start_lng = c(
        -87.623777,
        -87.6736628333333,
        -87.6776919292,-87.645361,
        -87.63483,
        -87.63483
      ),
      end_lat = c(
        41.90096,
        41.8472958333333,
        41.921525,
        42.00797192287,
        41.90230870122,
        41.90230870122
      ),
      end_lng = c(
        -87.623777,-87.646736,
        -87.707322,
        -87.6655023944,
        -87.627690528,
        -87.627690528
      ),
      member_casual = c("casual", "member", "casual", "member",
                        "member", "member")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

Comment: Are you using the same data or different `all_trip` vs `all_copies_in_trip`

Comment: I am using the same data. Sorry just edited my question

Comment: It is not what the duplicated output returns.  It just returns the duplicate leaving the first one out i.e. `duplicated(c(3, 3, 4, 5, 4))#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

Comment: Right, but doesn't the Wolcott entry come after Michigan? Also, someone mentioned to try [,c("rideable_type", "start_station_name", "end_station_name", "start_lat", "start_lng", "end_lat", "end_lng", "member_casual")]) ] but now I get "Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector."

Comment: It is me who suggested that.  But when I looked at your code, it seems to be legit

Comment: Thank you. I will edit question

Comment: Please try to include `dput` of few rows that shows the problem with the code

Comment: Based on your dput, I get only a single row as output `duplicated(all_trip[c("rideable_type", "start_station_name", "end_station_name", "start_lat", "start_lng", "end_lat", "end_lng", "member_casual")])
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE` i.e. `all_trip[duplicated(all_trip[c("rideable_type", "start_station_name", "end_station_name", "start_lat", "start_lng", "end_lat", "end_lng", "member_casual")]), ]
# A tibble: 1 × 11
  ride_id          rideable_type started_at          ended_at            start_station_n…`

Comment: do you find any difference in output with the dput you showed `trip_data`

Comment: Using dput and trip_data, the duplicate function outputs correctly

Comment: It is better to post an example that shows the issue so that we can dig deeper into it.

Comment: Is the `trip_data` or the `same_time_data` that should be checked

Comment: My mistake. Just the trip_data. Is there something else I should dput?

Comment: I meant have you changed the `trip_data` to the one that is causing the issue.  When I chekced earlier, it was returning a single row

Comment: Oh, the trip_data is from the data frame that is causing the issue. trip data <- dput(all_trip[1367:1372,])

Comment: what I meant is that is that subset data working properly or not. We would need a subset that doesn't work properly

Comment: the duplicated function is working properly on the subset data (trip_data), but the duplicated function isn't working on all_trip. I don't know how I can subset the part that isn't working

Comment: I would say take a random sample of the rows, check if that work or not

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up just discarding the original function because it was causing other issues as well.

Comment: Honestly, it is not clear to me why the original code didn't work.  As far as I can see from the other solution, it is just removing the 'ride_id'.  Probably, you selected only few columns in `duplicated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way

```
trip_data[trip_data %>% select(-ride_id) %>% duplicated(),]
```

output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 11
  ride_id          rideable_type started_at          ended_at            start_station_name       end_station_name   start_lat start_lng end_lat end_lng member_casual
  <chr>            <chr>         <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>                    <chr>                  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>        
1 15DE43740FDDCCC1 classic_bike  2021-06-18 18:28:38 2021-06-18 18:37:07 Wells St & Evergreen Ave Rush St & Cedar St      41.9     -87.6    41.9   -87.6 member
```

This seems to be the correct result.

Comment: I used your format on the original data frame "all_trip". After comparing both outputs, your format fixed the issue. Thank you! The formula I was using was creating other strange issues as well.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Remember that on Stack Overflow you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.